# Clarification in the Ethereum White Paper

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, ethereum

I was going through the Ethereum White Paper and it was mentioned that the scripting language implemented in bitcoin blockchain has a limitation of value-blindness and Blockchain-blindness (point 2 and 4 in the paper). I am finding it hard to comprehend what this means. It would be great if someone could help understand this with an example.

1. **Value Blindness:**

> There is no way for a UTXO script to provide
>   fine-grained control over the amount that can be withdrawn. For
>   example, one powerful use case of an oracle contract would be a
>   hedging contract, where A and B put in $1000 worth of BTC and after 30
>   days the script sends $1,000 worth of BTC to A and the rest to B. This
>   would require an oracle to determine the value of 1 BTC in USD[Note
>   3], but even then it is a massive improvement in terms of trust and
>   infrastructure requirement over the fully centralized solutions that
>   are available now. However, because UTXO are all-or-nothing, the only
>   way to achieve this is through the very inefficient hack of having
>   many UTXO of varying denominations (eg. one UTXO of 2k for every k up
>   to 30) and having O pick which UTXO to send to A and which to B.

2. **Blockchain-blindness**

> UTXO are blind to certain blockchain data such as the nonce and
>   previous block hash. This severely limits applications in gambling,
>   and several other categories, by depriving the scripting language of a
>   potentially valuable source of randomness.